# By the CATAPHORIC use of "the" may be understood the use of the definite article

Tags: subjects

> By the CATAPHORIC use of "the" may be understood the use of the definite article in a context where what follows the head noun, rather than what precedes it,enables us to pinpoint the reference uniquely.

From CGEL（A comprehensive grammar of the English language. by Quirk. et al）,Chapter.5.32

I can't understand this sentence. Can you point out the subject of it?

Comment: "CGEL" stands for "The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language." It's a different book. I'm guessing the structure of your example is similar to that of, e.g., "On a mountain stood a castle," with "castle" being the subject. In your case, I suppose the subject is *everything* from "the use" to the end of the sentence. The author had to switch the word order to make the sentence easier to read.

Comment: It just so happens that these two books have the same acronym.Thanks for the explanation,that makes sense.

Comment: Wow. That actually never occurred to me.